# Create a lock on insert/update of rows having a specific value

Tags: mysql, locking

In a MySQL transaction in InnoDB, a gap lock is created on a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` query in `REPEATABLE READ` mode.

So if a transaction T1 runs the query `` SELECT * FROM `inventory` WHERE `price`=45545 FOR UPDATE; `` and then T2 runs `` UPDATE `inventory` SET `color`=3 WHERE `price`=45545; ``, T2 stalls until T1 completes due to the gap lock. This behavior is useful since T1 maintains an invariant that it has an exclusive lock on all rows having `` `price`=45545 ``.

However, this doesn't seem to be the case when there are no rows having `` `price`=45545 `` to begin with. In that case, no gap lock is created, and T2 runs successfully, breaking the invariant.

Is there any way to force MySQL to take the gap lock even when no rows match?

Comment: Try using `between` instead of `=` for the gap lock.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I still get the same behavior.

Comment: Are you committing the transaction, or using autocommit? The lock is held only until the transaction commits.

Comment: Neither. Both transactions are active but there still isn't a lock.

Comment: An interesting behavior is that if T1 has modified any rows in that range before T2 runs its `UPDATE`, then T2 stalls until T1 commits.

Comment: Gap locks are there to prevent insertions, not updates. In your first scenario it is the actual row lock that prevents the record from bring updated by T2. In scenario 2, there is no sense to create any locks, since there is no matching record. How could mysql guess what to lock in that case? I do not understand what a successful update by T2 would break in this case. Scenario 3 in your comment indicates that the price column may not be indexed or it is not unique (not a big surprise), therefore any updates by T1 will lock larger ranges because more rows are scanned.